# install numpy.exe silently with batch file in windows

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, numpy

I want to create a batch file that helps multiple users install numpy on a Windows shared drive. Basically, users should not have to input options or perform any actions at all (as they would if they double-clicked the numpy executable installer).

A Python installation is **already present**. The users have to just run the batch file and install numpy into the default `Python\Lib\site-packages` location.

I've tried using the following commands:

```
numpy-1.6.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe /qn
numpy-1.6.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe /quiet
numpy-1.6.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe /passive
```

In all cases, the batch file is in the same directory as the executables and a graphical window pops up where the user has to click 'Next' again and again. Is there a way to run the install with ALL default options and not have user interaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the numpy install process is actually make of two installers. The outer one is NSIS, while the inner is python's distutils installer. All NSIS installers have the `/s` for silent installs, but this NSIS installer invokes the distutils installer.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any silent flags for the distutils installer. I see only two obvious options:

- compile numpy yourself and make it emit an msi installer (thus, should be able to silently be installed). Use `python setup.py bdist_msi`. If you prefer, you can generate an NSIS package using [bdist_nsi](http://bdist-nsi.sourceforge.net/).
- Use something like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to automate the distutils installer. Simply wait for the disutils window to appear & send it a series of keyboard shortcuts to automate the install.

The latter seems like the more practical solution. You could also try to get the python devs to get a silent flag into the distutils installer...

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Once clarification though; in the latter approach, I'd be building numpy from source, and **not** using the executable installer, right?

Comment: No. With the latter approach (using autoit), you can use the existing installer.

Comment: OK that sounds fine. Do you think that there could be an easier solution by building from source? I don't have too much experience with Windows scripting so if I could create a simple set of Python calls from the command line it might be easier

Comment: For windows, compiling it would be trouble all the way. You'll need to use the same visual c compiler used for building python. Then you'll need to get all the dependencies of numpy - like a FORTRAN compiler and probably some linear algebra optimization libraries. It would be a lot faster to write an autoit script (which is probably <50 lines). In the autoit full installation, there is a basic recorder which is a good starting point for the script.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I'll definitely look into this.

Answer (score 1):

No need to install this from source if you have the correct .exe package.

I grabbed that latest numpy .exe from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

and working from the downloads folder you just type this in the console:

```
easy_install c:\users\YourName\downloads\numpy‑MKL‑1.9.1.win32‑py2.7.exe
```

Comment: Thanks - this solved a related issue, trying to install psutil :-)

Answer (score 0):

The method I used to install unattended is as follows:

```
%PYTHON_PATH%\Scripts\easy_install c:\temp\numpy-1.9.0.zip
```