# How do I install the Python psutil library on a Windows XP machine without an internet connection?

Tags: python, windows, psutil

I have a Windows XP machine which I'm trying to deploy to with an automated script without an internet connection. Part of my Python script requires the `pymodbus3` library and though I've managed to get a lot of the required packages installed, I'm struggling to sort out `psutil`.

If I try installing it from the source I get the following error message:

```
D:\ZP300\Scripts\Z300Diagnostics>easy_install psutil-2.2.1.tar.gz
Processing psutil-2.2.1.tar.gz
Writing c:\docume~1\admini~1\locals~1\temp\easy_install-lgcclk\psutil-2.2.1\setup.cfg
Running psutil-2.2.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\docume~1\admini~1\locals~1\temp\easy_install-lgcclk\psutil-2.2.1\egg-dist-tmp-x_z0ii
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs\_build'
error: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).
```

If I try to use the windows installer, there doesn't seem to be a way to run the installer without launching the GUI.

Is there a way to install from source without visual studio 2010 or to launch the windows installer without requiring a user?

Answer (score 1):

Found [a solution here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27768695/15369) and it was actually easier than I imagined:

```
easy_install psutil-2.2.1.win32-py3.3.exe
```

Comment: You can also use `pip install psutil-2.2.1-cp33-none-win32.whl`.